# finding the third derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the following equation :

$u_t+2uu_x=u_{xx}$

and the following similarity variables :

$z=\frac{x}{t^{1/2}}\quad and\quad u=\frac{w(z)}{t^{1/2}}$

Any ideas how I would go about finding $u_{xx}$ and $u_{xxx}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your equations for $u$ and $z$ yield $u= x^{-1}w(z)z$. Then we get $u_x = -x^{-2}w(z)z$, $u_{xx}=2x^{-3}w(z)z$ and $u_{xxx} = -6x^{-4}w(z)z$.